# how to add to option additional field similar to legend

Tags: javascript, html

I wonder if there is a way to add a custom caption to each option value in a list similar to legend. So it should be for example `<option>01</option><legend>Mercedes</legend>`. The legend field shouldn't be used in any further computations only the value chosen as option should be there. My current code:

```
<form action="./index.html" method="GET">
Device Id:
  <input type="hidden" value="" name="idb" class="idb" />
  <select data-placeholder="Wpisz tutaj numery urządzenia" multiple class="chosen-select">
    <option value="" hidden></option>
    <option>01</option>
    <option>02</option>
    <option>03</option>
    <option>04</option>
    <option>05</option>
    <option>06</option>
    <option>07</option>
    <option>08</option>
    <option>09</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>

  </select>

<input type="submit" value="Wyślij"/>
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.chosen-select').chosen({width: "20%"}).change(function(el) {
    let selectedOptions = [].slice.call(this.selectedOptions);
    let optionValues = selectedOptions.map(o => o.value);
    $(".idb").val(optionValues.join(","));
  });

  // to show the output

});
</script>
```

Comment: whether is it necessary to display the value also?

Comment: It is necessary to display the value in legend to the end user

Comment: What kind of visualization you want to have? An image or sketch would be helpful.

Comment: It's just should be displayed along the option value so: option -- legend for example: 01 -- mercedes

Comment: Wouldn't <option value="01">01 - Mercedes</option> work?